# How to write Orderby Clause with where clause to sort data

Tags: php, sorting, stored-procedures

I'm trying sort MySQL data in table but my problem is that my query is sorting all the data my table looks like

```
Word        | Meaning                  | Synonym      | Antonym
definitely  | without doubt            | certainly    |possibly
great       | of an extent, amount     | considerable |little
zeal        | great energy             | passion      | indiference
zealot      | a person who is fanatical|fanatic       | moderate
zealous     | having or showing zeal.  | fervent      | apathetic
```

so when I search let's say word starting witH `z` then I get:

```
Word        | Meaning                  | Synonym      | Antonym
zeal        | great energy             | passion      | indiference
zealot      | a person who is fanatical|fanatic       | moderate
zealous     | having or showing zeal.  | fervent      | apathetic
```

now I want to perform sorting on these searched data but my sort query is sorting the all data.

My stored procedure looks like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SortContent`()
BEGIN
SELECT * from dictionarysearch ORDER BY word ASC;
END
```

and my PHP code is like:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['search_btn'])){
  $search=$_GET['search'];
  $result=GetWords(mysqli_escape_string($conn,$search));
}
/*if(isset($_GET['q'])){
      $id=$_GET['q'];
      $result=GetWordsById($id);
    }*/
    if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
      $sort=$_GET['sort'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
      if($sort=="asc"){
        $result=SortContent();//Here i'm calling  a function which is calling the store procedure
      }
      if($sort=="desc"){
        $result=SortContent2();
      }
     
    }

  
    else{
  $result=GetAdminWords();
}
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
  ?>  
    <thead>
      <tr>
        
        <th>Word</th>
        <th>Meaning</th>
        <th>Synonym</th>
        <th>Antonym</th>
       
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         
          <td><a href="view.php?q=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['word'];?></a></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['meaning'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['synonym'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['antonym'];?></td>
         <td><a href="admin.php?id1=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> <a onClick="javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');" href="view.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <?php
  }?>
  </table>
```

So I want to know how I can write  a query so that it sorts only selected data and I have set id autoincrement.

Comment: "my problem is that my query is sorting all the data " that's because you're selecting all the data. Your query needs a WHERE clause as well to restrict it to whatever your search term is. Look up the syntax for WHERE if you don't know it. You can have WHERE and ORDER BY in the same statement, you don't need multiple separate queries

Comment: @ADyson please tell me how to do it i dont know about it

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php . Have you actually tried to look it up or anything? It's pretty much the second thing you normally learn about SQL after a SELECT command. Doesn't your GetWordsById function already call a query containing a WHERE clause?

Comment: i dont know how to use orderby and where clause together my GetWordsbyId is not using orderby i have not written two clauses together

Comment: Surely you know how to use google though? Surely you've found the MySQL documentation which explains the syntax? Surely you found a tutorial site with lots of mysql examples?
 Start with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html This is day 1 basic stuff, you really should not need it feeding to you on a spoon. https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/order_by.php shows it _very_ clearly. That site is generally on the first page of google if you search about mysql. Research it, try something, learn how to find basic information yourself. If you get stuck with an actual code attempt, ask again.

Comment: @ADYson i'm trying to figure it out since yesterday and yes i have googled,i have read documentation, i have tried different possibilities but nothing worked and if you think it's worthless you can close this discussion Thank you i appreciate your time

Comment: Well you didn't show us what you tried or what went wrong with it. Your question and comments reads like you hadn't even looked what the syntax was. So I apologise but that's the appearance you were giving. As I mentioned, if you provide you actual attempt to solve it, we can help to fix it. Basically you just need to include an order by clause in your query called by GetWordsById, and forget the other two queries. It's probably easier not to use stored procedures, then you can build up the SQL string based on the currently selected sort direction.

Comment: I didnt mean to be rude it's just when you try very hard and not get desired results i apologise for that..

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a stored Procedure for this. I suggest that the following code will work for you...

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['search_btn']) && strlen($_GET['search'])){
    $search = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_GET['search']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dummydata WHERE info LIKE '".$search."%'";
    if(isset($_GET['sort']) && in_array($_GET['sort'], array('ASC', 'DESC'))){
        $sort=$_GET['sort'];
        $sql .= " ORDER BY info ".$sort;
    }
    //echo "<h3>".$sql."</h3>";

    if (($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))!==false) {
    ?>  
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Word</th>
        <th>Meaning</th>
        <th>Synonym</th>
        <th>Antonym</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        //echo "<pre>".var_export($row,true)."</pre>";
     ?>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="view.php?q=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['word'];?></a></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['meaning'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['synonym'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['antonym'];?></td>
          <td>Your action url here.... </td>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
   </table>
   <?php   
    } else {
        echo "<h3>Problem with SQL</h3>";
    }
}

?>
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: I work with store procedure  but thank you for your time and effort @Clinton